# How to simplify fractions?

Tags: c#, math, fractions

How to simplify a fraction in C#? For example, given `1 11/6`, I need it simplified to `2 5/6`.

Comment: What if the input was "1 10/6", would you want "2 4/6" or "2 2/3"?

Comment: @sepp2k Since 2 2/3 is the simplist form then i assume he wants this.

Answer (score 8):

If all you want is to turn your fraction into a mixed number whose fractional part is a proper fraction like the previous answers assumed, you only need to add `numerator / denominator` to the whole part of the number and set the numerator to `numerator % denominator`. Using loops for this is completely unnecessary.

However the term "simplify" usually refers to reducing a fraction to its lowest terms. Your example does not make clear whether you want that as well, as the example is in its lowest terms either way.

Here's a C# class that normalizes a mixed number, such that each number has exactly one representation: The fractional part is always proper and always in its lowest terms, the denominator is always positive and the sign of the whole part is always the same as the sign of the numerator.

```
using System;

public class MixedNumber {
    public MixedNumber(int wholePart, int num, int denom)
    {  
        WholePart = wholePart;
        Numerator = num;
        Denominator = denom;
        Normalize();
    }

    public int WholePart { get; private set; }
    public int Numerator { get; private set; }
    public int Denominator { get; private set; }

    private int GCD(int a, int b)
    {  
        while(b != 0)
        {  
            int t = b;
            b = a % b;
            a = t;
        }
        return a;
    }

    private void Reduce(int x) {
        Numerator /= x;
        Denominator /= x;
    }

    private void Normalize() {
        // Add the whole part to the fraction so that we don't have to check its sign later
        Numerator += WholePart * Denominator;

        // Reduce the fraction to be in lowest terms
        Reduce(GCD(Numerator, Denominator));

        // Make it so that the denominator is always positive
        Reduce(Math.Sign(Denominator));

        // Turn num/denom into a proper fraction and add to wholePart appropriately
        WholePart = Numerator / Denominator;
        Numerator %= Denominator;
    }

    override public String ToString() {
        return String.Format("{0} {1}/{2}", WholePart, Numerator, Denominator);
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
csharp> new MixedNumber(1,11,6);     
2 5/6
csharp> new MixedNumber(1,10,6);   
2 2/3
csharp> new MixedNumber(-2,10,6);  
0 -1/3
csharp> new MixedNumber(-1,-10,6); 
-2 -2/3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int unit = 1;
int numerator = 11;
int denominator = 6;

while(numerator >= denominator)
{
    numerator -= denominator;
    if(unit < 0)
        unit--;
    else
        unit++;
}
```

Then do whatever you like with the variables.

Note that this isn't particularly general.... in particular I doubt it's going to play well with negative numbers (edit: might be better now)

Comment: Seems like you should do `numerator >= denominator`. Which would let 6/6 == 1

Comment: I think that works, but I also seem to think being awake at 5am on Stack Overflow is not a good idea, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: haha, so true. That's closer, but think about if you have `-11/6`, it will never enter your loop. `-11` is not `>= 6`

Answer (score 1):

```
int num = 11;
int denom = 6;
int unit = 1;
while (num >= denom)
{
  num -= denom;
  unit++;
}
```

Sorry I didn't fully understand that part about keeping track of the unit values.

Comment: this seems to say that 11/6 == 5/6. you're chopping off the whole number part.

Comment: This needs to track the unit... a unit variable along with num and denom, which gets incremented in the while loop, would do the trick.

Comment: The loop was always intended, I just didnt understand they they wanted to keep track of the unit value.

Comment: There's a lot of downvoting but not a lot of explanation for it. Comments are here for a reason, guys!

Comment: Assigning it to a long is meaningless, and will produce an incorrect result.  You might as well keep it in fractional form.  Call counter what it is: Units (or Whole Number part).

Comment: +1 to Robert. as it is, all of this code could be done by simply storing `num/denom` in a long

Comment: Ok, I see your point, I just though precision could be nice here.

Comment: @Jim: `int` will still produce an incorrect result.  Think about it: you're trying to store 5/6 in an integer variable.  If it compiles and runs (which I don't think it will, not without some casting), `fract` will contain **two,** not the expected value of 2+5/6

Comment: That's better.  I made some additional minor fixes, and removed my downvote.  You can see the changes here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5287530/revisions

Comment: a) This will not work if either of the numbers are negative. b) Using a loop for this is way too complicated, all you need is integer division and modulus. c) I'm not sure that making the fraction proper is all the OP wants - it's not what simplifying a fraction usually means.

Answer (score 0):

to simplify the fraction `6/11` you would see if you could get both to line up by the same number greater than 1 and divide.

So

- `2,4,6,8,10,12` no
- `1,3,6,9,12` no
- `4,8` no
- `5,10` no
- `6,12` no
- `7` no
- `8` no
- `9` no.

No will be the answer for all so it is already in simplest. There is no more to be done.