# How to simplify a fraction when both nums are ints

Tags: java, fractions

I must simplify a fraction as much as possible. Must be Java.

This is what I have so far

```
if (numerator != 0)
    {

        numerator += denominator;
        denominator += numerator /2;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simplify fractions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287514/how-to-simplify-fractions)

Comment: Your try looks completely irrelevant. I'm sure you can find a proper algorithm for that. You simply need the largest common divisor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start off by saying that you need more practice with Java. Your code isn't even close...

```
if (numerator != 0) 
    {
        int common = gcd(Math.abs(numerator), denominator); // Gets a common denominator and uses abs to  make sure it is positive.
        numerator = numerator / common; // Divides top number by common #
        denominator = denominator / common; // Divides bottom number by common #
    }
```

You'll need to `import java.util.Math;` and you'll have to also get the GCD like i did. To get the GCD you say

```
while (num1 != num2)
    {
        if (num1 > num2)
        {
            num1 = num1 - num2;
        }
        else
        {
            num2 = num2 - num1;
        }
    }
    return num1;
```

I hope this makes sense to you. It's not too hard after you understand it. Let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: I don't get what the while loop does in the GCD method

Comment: @user3295249 I ran the while loop to make sure that the numerator doesn't equal the denominator. If it did, it would simplify to 1. Since it doesn't equal 1, if numerator > den, it will subtract the den. Vice Versa for the denominator

Comment: That gcd method is horribly inefficient. Use the one from @SpiderPig's answer.

Answer (score 2):

btw. the shortest possible gcd method is this.

```
static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if(b == 0) return a;
    else return gcd(b, a%b);
}
```

it's also a lot faster than using subtraction.

Comment: why would you mod a by b? how would that give you a value??