# Reducing Fractions

Tags: vb.net, fractions

My code:

```
Private Sub btnReduce_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReduce.Click

    Call Reduce()

End Sub

Function Reduce() As Single

    Dim num As Integer = txtNum.Text
    Dim deno As Integer = txtDeno.Text

    For i = 1 To deno Step +1
        If num Mod i = 0 Then
            num = num / i
        End If

        If deno Mod i = 0 Then
            deno = deno / i
        End If

    Next

    lblOutputNum.Text = num
    lblOutputDeno.Text = deno

End Function
```

When I enter 2/4 it gives me 1/2. But when I enter 3/6 it gives me 1/1. Does anyone know why it does this? As I can't figure this out. Thanks to anyone who can.

Comment: Please consider reading links given to you in previous version of [reduce fraction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093302/visual-basic-reducing-fractions) question. I don't see code that computed [GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) as suggested in linked [simplify fractoions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287514/how-to-simplify-fractions).

Comment: GCD is really not language specific.... [GCD](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gcd) - and corresponding [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: I'm still not getting this, I've using the Euclidean Algorithm, nothing's working.

Answer (score 2):

You can't divide numerator and denominator independently from each other or you will change the fraction's value:

```
For i = 1 To Math.Min(deno, num)/2 Step +1
    If num Mod i = 0 And deno Mod i = 0 Then
        num = num / i
        deno = deno / i
    End If
Next
```

Keep in mind that this approach is not very performant. You need to divide numerator and denominator by their greatest common divisor. The GCD can be calculated with the euclidean algorithm.

Comment: +1. OP does not seem to be interested in using GCD as it was already suggested yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Using Nico's example, I managed to reduce the fraction even further.

```
For i = 1 To Math.Min(deno, num)/2 Step +1
 If num Mod i = 0 And deno Mod i = 0 Then
  num = num / i
  deno = deno / i
 End If
 If i > 1 Then
  While nume Mod i = 0 And deno Mod i = 0
   nume = nume / i
   deno = deno / i
  End While
 End If
Next
```